# Strange ListView and MouseArea behaviour in QML

Tags: listview, onclick, qml, mouseevent, touch-event

My QML application has a lateral menu (`ListView`) and based on what item the user chooses it loads a different page. My problem is that sometimes the touch input is registered but not executed until the screen recives another input (not necessarily on an element of the list) and this happens at random, at least from my initial tests. Everything else works apparently fine and I have no clue on what could be the cause. I tried to console.log() each element to confirm this behaviour and the output is in fact not displayed until a second input occours. The app also has a `MouseArea` which fills the entire screen, after any touch/mouse event a timer starts and if it doesn't recive any input an "idle" page is shown after 2 minutes. At first I thought that this could somehow trap the mouse events but getting rid of it doesn't solve the issue
This is the code of the timer:

```
Timer {
    id: timerStandby
    interval: 120000
    triggeredOnStart: false
    onTriggered: mainLoader.source = "StandbyMenu.qml"
    }
}

// Fill screen to catch user input and hide cursor
MouseArea {
    id: timerStandbyArea
    z: 100
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    cursorShape: Qt.BlankCursor
    onClicked: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
        testTch.visible = true
    }
    onPressed: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
        testTch.visible = true
    }
    onReleased: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
        testTch.visible = false
    }
    onDoubleClicked: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
    }
    onPressAndHold: {
        timerStandby.restart()
        mouse.accepted = false;
        //console.log("start timer")
    }
}
```

My next assumption was that my list was the issue but a simple `ColumnLayout` behaves in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using QML profiler I noticed that the `OnClicked` event doesn't always return the `released()` signal. As a temporary solution I've decided to use `onPressed` for that particular list, still not sure why this happens though